# PopupWindow Control

Tags: android, touch, popupwindow, dismiss

The green view is a `CandidateView` which extends from `PopupWindow` and containing a `ListView` that displays some candidates when user type on `KeyboardView`.

My demand is :

1. When user touches the red area or the edit text , the candidate view should be dismissed.
2. The candidate view should NOT be dismissed when user touches the `KeyboardView`.

PS: The keyboard view is a custom keyboard that extends from `android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView`

My problem is :
If I set `setOutsideTouchable(true);` for the `CandidateView`, it will be dismissed when I touch the second key on keyboard，which is not what I want. Then, I begin consider listening to the touch event on red area and edit text and in `onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)` method, I checked if the touched view is keyboard by `if (v.getClass().equals(KeyboardView.class))`, if not , dismiss the CandidateView. This approach didn't make any difference until I do `setFocusable(false);` for the `CandidateView`. So far, so good. But as I make the `CandidateView` not focusable, the `ListView` inside the `CandidateView` will not receive `OnItemClick` event any more.

Now, I think, making my `CandidateView` NOT to dismiss on outside touch event while keep touchable(list item clickable) at the meantime, will be the solution to my problem.

[image]

Comment: Why not use [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake because I need to implement input method of my own :)